# Replace Literal Star (*) ... but Only Within Parentheses

Tags: php, regex, recursion

this my next question for regex.
Honestly, i want to build animation for math multiply , when their input some formula, their will get animation to describe where is this number will counting, this part of my code.

```
$pattern = '([*])';
$replace = '||';
$stringAsli = (123*1.23*(0.12/8))*(123*512+40);
$replaceResult= str_replace($pattern,$replace,$stringAsli);
```

but i got result :

```
(123||1.23||(0.12/8))||(123||512+40)
```

i want result like this

```
(123||1.23||(0.12/8))*(123||512+40);
```

**Extended Requirements**

In this special case with quoted strings:

```
("123*1.23*n"*"(0.12/8)")*("123*512"+40)
```

should become

```
("123||1.23||n"$"(0.12/8)")*("123||512"+40)
```

In other words, still replace the `*` inside the brackets, but if we're inside a quoted strings we replace with `||`, and if not we replace with `$`

Comment: Are you saying that you only want to replace `*` when it is inside parentheses?

Comment: I believe you mean `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace` in your example code based on the result you received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Recursive Regex and Lambda Replacement

To safely get into your parentheses, we need to use a recursive regex. Fortunately, PHP supports this. Do it like this (see the output of the online demo):

```
$mystring = "(123*1.23*(0.12/8))*(123*512+40)";
$nested_parentheses_regex="~\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)~";
$replaced = preg_replace_callback(
                    $nested_parentheses_regex,
                    function($m) { return str_replace("*","||",$m[0]);},
                    $mystring
                    );
echo $replaced;
```

See the output of [the online demo](http://ideone.com/AEVtSO).

**Explanation**

- The recursive regex `\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)` matches (potentially) nested parentheses
- The `preg_replace_callback` function calls an anonymous function which replaces every `*` with a `||` within the match (which is a set of nested parentheses.

### Extended Requirements

You now asked that inside the parentheses, when the asterisk is not inside quotes, we return `$`

Use this:

```
$mystring = '("123*1.23*n"*"(0.12/8)")*("123*512"+40)';
$nested_parentheses_regex ="~\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)~"; 

$replaced = preg_replace_callback($nested_parentheses_regex,
    function($m) {
          return preg_replace_callback(
               '~"[^"]*"|(\*)~', // complete "quote" OR capture * to Group 1
               function($n) {
                   // Not inside quotes?
                   if(isset($n[1])) return "\$";
                   else {  // we matched a "full quote"  
                      return str_replace("*","||",$n[0]);
                   }
                   }, 
                $m[0] // this is a (full (set) of parentheses)
                ); // end inner callback
    },
    $mystring
); // end outer callback
echo $replaced;
```

Comment: Nice use of the `++` quantifier, that's exactly what I was trying to remember how to do and just opted to go a different route instead.

Comment: @Steve Buzonas: to make it helpful to everyone else - it's called a "possessive quantifier": http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Comment: hi thanks @zx81 its really work , but i get one case again , one variable i append "" like : $mystring = '("123*1.23*n"*"(0.12/8)")*("123*512"+40)'; the n is * will append in n value, and the result must like : '("123||1.23||n"$"(0.12/8)")*("123||512"+40)', the * inside " is replaced by || BUT outside the * replaced by $.
Please Help me, this case must finishing today. Regards. :)

Comment: Not a problem, give me a moment. :)

Comment: Okay, done!!! See the `Extended Requirements` section. :) Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: yeah, ur master of regex! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Implemented a regex-free solution just for fun:

*It might be even faster than regex ;-D*

```
$str = '(123*1.23*(0.12/8))*(123*512+40)';

$depth = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); ++$i) {
    $char = $str[$i];

    switch ($char) {
        case '(':
            ++$depth;
            break;
        case ')':
            --$depth;
            break;
        case '*':
            if ($depth != 0) {
                $str = substr_replace($str, '||', $i, 1);
                ++$i;
            }
            break;
    }
}

echo $str;
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/IOpOl9

Comment: I was halfway to writing same thing with `if` instead of `switch`. +1 This solution will work best.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: my 1st revision was also with `if` then realized that `switch` is what we usually use for FSAs (this is not a real or the best example of FSA though)

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im `This solution will work best` Yes it's fun and it will work, but why would it work "best"? (Why would it work better than my regex solution?)

Comment: @zx81: honestly both of them are hard to understand and maintain (without decent amount of comments around) :-)

Comment: @zerkms Ha, from my standpoint, these recursive parentheses (or brackets, curlies, whatever) regexps are part of my standard arsenal, so I would only need one line of comments (`// regex for nested pars`) as the code is otherwise short and obvious. So for me it's far easier to maintain, expand etc than a custom parser (and I guess the idea of regex is to save us from writing custom parsers). But yeah, it's a matter of what one is used to! :)

Comment: @zx81: indeed - `$matchNestedParens = "~\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)~";` --- and you don't even need a comment (and even look on a regex when you read this code)

Comment: @zerkms You're right, that's a great way to do without comments. Great thought, thank you. :) Hey by the way, he added to the requirements: when we're inside `"quotes"` inside parentheses, we still replace with `||`, but otherwise (still inside parentheses) we replace with `$`... Just did the regex version, giving you a heads up in case you're keen to do the parser. :)

Comment: @zx81: it's easy to add there, but I'm off. The trial for me writing code for free in this question is ended :-)

Comment: I hear you. Nice chatting, thanks for your thoughts, see you another time. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to replace only a literal `*` within parenthesis that will get tricky and require a recursive regex pattern.

A recursive regex pattern for nested parenthesis looks something like `\((?>(?>[^()]+)|(?R))*\)`.

```
\(               # matches a literal (
(?>              # starts an atomic group
    (?>          # starts an atomic group
        [^()]+   # matches 1 or more characters that are not parenthesis
    )            # ends atomic group
    |            # allows an alternative pattern
    (?R)         # allows the pattern to be recursed
)                # ends atomic group
*                # signifies the pattern match 0 or more times
\)               # matches a literal )
```

The pattern will allow you to get all of the matches of everything within parenthesis.

```
$pattern = '/\((?>(?>[^()]+)|(?R))*\)/';
$subject  = '(123*1.23*(0.12/8))*(123*512+40)';

$replacements = $matches = array();

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

To do the additional replacements on all of these groups I decided to create an array of literal replacement pairs.

```
foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    $replacements[$match] = preg_replace('/[*]/', '||', $match);
}
```

This gives you an array in `$replacements` that has a key of what to replace and a value of what to replace it with and you can use it in `str_replace` against your original string.

```
$result = str_replace(array_keys($replacements), array_values($replacements), $subject);
```

Comment: Hey Steve, FYI the outer parentheses in your recursive regex don't serve any purpose, they can be taken out. Also the term for `(?>` is `atomic group` (when you say `non-capturing group` people understand `(?:`